# Compare data between 2 different source

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a two datasets coming from 2 sources and i have to compare and find the mismatches. One from excel and other from Datawarehouse.

From excel `Source_Excel`

```
+-----+-------+------------+----------+
| id  | name  | City_Scope | flag     |
+-----+-------+------------+----------+
| 101 | Plate | NY|TN      | Ready    |
| 102 | Nut   | NY|TN      | Sold     |
| 103 | Ring  | TN|MC      | Planning |
| 104 | Glass | NY|TN|MC   | Ready    |
| 105 | Bolt  | MC         | Expired  |
+-----+-------+------------+----------+
```

From DW `Source_DW`

```
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| id  | name  | City | flag     |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| 101 | Plate | NY   | Ready    |
| 101 | Plate | TN   | Ready    |
| 102 | Nut   | TN   | Expired  |
| 103 | Ring  | MC   | Planning |
| 104 | Glass | MC   | Ready    |
| 104 | Glass | NY   | Ready    |
| 105 | Bolt  | MC   | Expired  |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
```

Unfortunately Data from excel comes with separator for one column. So i have to use [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function) function to split that into individual rows. so i got the below output after splitting the excel source data.

```
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| id  | name  | item | flag     |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
| 101 | Plate | NY   | Ready    |
| 101 | Plate | TN   | Ready    |
| 102 | Nut   | NY   | Sold     |
| 102 | Nut   | TN   | Sold     |
| 103 | Ring  | TN   | Planning |
| 103 | Ring  | MC   | Planning |
| 104 | Glass | NY   | Ready    |
| 104 | Glass | TN   | Ready    |
| 104 | Glass | MC   | Ready    |
| 105 | Bolt  | MC   | Expired  |
+-----+-------+------+----------+
```

Now my expected output is something like this.

```
+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+
| ID  | Result   | Flag_mismatch | City_Missing |
+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+
| 101 | No_Error |               |              |
| 102 | Error    | Yes           | Yes          |
| 103 | Error    | No            | Yes          |
| 104 | Error    | Yes           | No           |
| 105 | No_Error |               |              |
+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

Logic:

1. I have to find if there are any mismatches in flag values.
2. After splitting if there are any city missing, then that should be reported.

Assume that there wont be any Name and city mismatches.

As a intial step, I'm trying to get the Mismatch rows and I have tried below query. It is not giving me any output. Please suggest where am going wrong.[**Check Fiddle Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ab1500d78f47409e717ddad55c41cc9e)

```
select a.id,a.name,split.item,a.flag from source_excel a 
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8k(a.city_scope,'|') split
where not exists (
select a.id,split.item 
from source_excel a 
join source_dw b 
on a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name and a.flag=b.flag and split.item=b.city
)
```

**Update**

I have tried and got close to the answers with the help of temporary tables. [Updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0aede43298890a34da043ebdd91ad98b) . But not sure how to do without temp tables

Comment: If you're on 2012, I suggest "updating" to `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`, as it does have a speed improvement.

Comment: As what your question, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: Sure @Larnu, I will update to `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`. Thanks for the tips. Regarding my question, It is not giving any output. I have shown that in Fiddle. As I first step, I want to get the mismatch rows first. So tried that query

Comment: Information like why it isn't working should be in your question, not implied via an external web link.

Comment: I agree. I have edited the question now. @Larnu

Comment: In your sub query, you're declaring your table `source_excel` again and giving it the same alias (which is a bad idea too), this means you're referencing the object inside the subquery, in side. That means that the `NOT EXISTS` doesn't really make a lot of sense. Also, you show your expected results, but your attempt looks nothing like your attempt. Where are the columns `Flag_mismatch` and `City_Missing`in your attempt, fo example?

Comment: Also, `a` and `b` (especially when you reuse `a`) isn't a good idea for aliases. Use good aliasing: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: With the tips and suggestions, I have tried and got close to the answers with the help of temporary tables. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0aede43298890a34da043ebdd91ad98b) . But not sure  how to do without temp tables @Larnu

Comment: Whether an object is temporary or not doesn't change how it behaves.

Comment: True! @Larnu But My requirement is not to use `TEMP` tables.